# Prolog find similar letters in 2 words

Tags: prolog

i have such problem, i need to find longest word consists of letters from 2 words, and this letters must be in same order like in original words, for example `xabred` and  `pppaed` must return `aed`. I have no idea how to do this in Prolog

Comment: "abc" and "cba" would produce three solutions: "a", "b", and "c"?

Comment: In prolog, you can use `atom_chars(abc, [a,b,c])` to go between an atom and its list of characters. Then write your predicate to work on a list of elements. Start with that.

Comment: Yes it will produce a, b, c

Comment: Then you'll need a predicate that takes two atomic strings and produces a list. Your predicate should convert the atomic strings to lists of characters using `atom_chars`, then it can generate list sequences of atom chars that match between the two lists, then choose the longest lists, and finally use `atom_chars` to convert back to an atomic string.

Comment: @mbratch  i have no idea how to do this, i make a list using `atom_chars`, but i don't know what i must do next. Can you give me an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the requirements correctly, the request is for a predicate which will (restated) find the longest substring in two given strings (atoms actually). If there is more than at the same, longest length, then all need to be listed. This says that the result is a list of one or more words.

Here's a stab at it which does the job, but it seems it may be a bit "clunky" and inefficient, particularly if you consider very long strings:

```
% Give a list of the longest matching words (substrings)
matchwords(W1, W2, Results) :-
    setof(R, matchw(W1, W2, R), RSet), % Collect all the matching substrings
                                       % and their lengths
    reverse(RSet, Set),                % Order by longest first
    highest(Set, Results).             % keep only the highest ones

% match atom-string W1 and W2 yielding atom-string Result of length N
matchw(W1, W2, N-Result) :-
    atom_chars(W1, A1),
    atom_chars(W2, A2),
    matchl(A1, A2, R),
    length(R, N),
    atom_chars(Result, R).

% find a matching sublist between the first two lists
matchl([H|T1], [H|T2], [H|T]) :-
    matchl(T1, T2, T).
matchl([H1|T1], [H2|T2], R) :-
    H1 \= H2,
    ( matchl(T1, [H2|T2], R) ; matchl([H1|T1], T2, R) ).
matchl([], _, []).
matchl([_|_], [], []).

% Keep the highest elements at the front of a list of N-W pairs
highest([_-W], [W]).
highest([N1-W1,N2-_|_], [W1]) :-
    N1 > N2.
highest([N1-W1,N2-W2|T], [W1|WT]) :-
    N1 = N2,
    highest([N2-W2|T], WT).
```

A couple of examples:

```
| ?- matchwords(xabred, pppaed, Matches).

Matches = [aed] ? a

(2 ms) no
| ?- matchwords(abcdef, acbedf, Matches).

Matches = [acef,acdf,abef,abdf] ? a

no
```

What this boils down to is the [Longest Common Sequence Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem). The code above does not attempt to implement the imperative solutions provided in the article.

Answer (score 2):

Let's first find *any* common sub-sequence of characters (I assume we are working with lists of characters):

```
common(Xs, Ys, [C|Cs]) :-
    append(_,[C|Xs1],Xs),
    append(_,[C|Ys1],Ys),
    common(Xs1, Ys1, Cs).
common(_, _, []).
```

This produces all solutions on backtracking:

```
?- common([a, b, c, d], [e, c, d, b], Cs).
Cs = [b]
Yes (0.00s cpu, solution 1, maybe more)
Cs = [c, d]
Yes (0.00s cpu, solution 2, maybe more)
Cs = [c]
Yes (0.00s cpu, solution 3, maybe more)
Cs = [d]
Yes (0.02s cpu, solution 4, maybe more)
Cs = []
Yes (0.03s cpu, solution 5)
```

You could now collect all solutions with findall/3 or setof/3, and filter out the longest ones.  Alternatively, the following shows how to modify the code such that it returns the longest solutions first:

```
ordered_common(Xs, Ys, Cs) :-
    le_min_length(Xs, Ys, Cs),
    common(Xs, Ys, Cs).

le_min_length([_|Xs], [_|Ys], [_|Zs]) :-
    le_min_length(Xs, Ys, Zs).
le_min_length(_, _, []).
```

That way, you can cut the search once it has delivered a solution you like.

```
?- ordered_common([a, b, c, d], [e, c, d, b], Cs).
Cs = [c, d]
Yes (0.00s cpu, solution 1, maybe more)
```

Comment: Nice. The `common/3` could take the place of my `matchl/3`. Depending upon the strings, `matchl` is fewer inferences. For example, if you use `[a,b,c,d,e,f]` and `[a,c,b,e,d,f]`, then `matchl` is very roughly 40% the number of inferences used by `common/3` to find all of the solutions.

Answer (score 1):

```
sl(A, B, C) :-
    atom_chars(A, Alist),
    atom_chars(B, Blist),
    intersection(Alist, Blist, Clist),
    atom_chars(C, Clist).
```

Test run:

```
?- sl(xabred, pppaed, X).
X = aed.
```

Comment: This will not always give a correct answer, Sergey. For example, `sl(abcdef,acbedf,L).` yields, `L = abcdef`, whereas the correct answers in this case would be `acef`, `acdf`, `abef`, and `abdf`. I think `intersection` causes trouble here since it doesn't enforce list order (it being a set operation).